# Sending data from client to server vie SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am fairly new to ssh and still learning it. Recently I have made a tunnel connection with an ssh host and managed to successfully transfer data/files from my machine to the server with the command: `scp file.extension user@hostIP:/directory/directory`.

While this was successful, I am kinda struggling to reverse it, sending data/files from the server to the client. How would one go about completing that? Do I need to make some changes to ssh_config or just CLI commands are enough?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the order:

```
scp user@hostIP:/directory/directory file.extension
```

that's accomplishing the invert operation, off course, assuming that the address is correct, the file exists and you have the necessary privileges.